# Is it free to add a cluster key to a bigquery table after it's been created?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm wondering if adding a cluster key to a bq table is free.  I would think that it's not free since there's a cost to shuffle the data in order to sort the key.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#modifying-cluster-spec), change cluster definition is a free operation, but the cluster definition will apply only to new data:

> When a table is converted from non-clustered to clustered or the clustered column set is changed, automatic re-clustering only works from that time onward. For example, a non-clustered 1 PB table that is converted to a clustered table using tables.update still has 1 PB of non-clustered data. Automatic re-clustering only applies to any new data committed to the table after the update

So to apply to all data in table, you will need to recreate it. Using the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` to do this operation will cost the table size in query. Also, this will cause the long-term storage became active again.